# Different RSA public key generated on Android

Tags: java, android, openssl, rsa, spongycastle

I was able to generate a public key in my Java desktop environment and I got something like this

> `Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits modulus: 101700973019391285593457598101942678753508114287289699162184623605939671495532511783006850112834969917970271633181351680298749946797462542179729127916916336425952724141383800466274935950042225686754068132826643586090512962724382324158485291344703936377718522573879330753020035687831145457530843148690890911921 public exponent: 65537`

But on Android device, when I get the key as a string and use `KeyFactory` to generate the public key, I am getting this:

> `OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=90d3b5cefc50dc42828cee8d718876f7573b4c9287dddf808e73cb66266c2004165217f86d0f0192de0bb88b3aac2002303ee8b1c926e9bc54189a5ec5a12bb293df0b3c6ff2458a63098f712f0b72218ce301c38de3971ae8c6c646160a5e2e24dc07679e5a82ada1233ecf5eca3d0d1f483d1c9f059
>    a23deed537c670b70b1,publicExponent=10001}`

There is discrepancy in the keys. I have tried SpongyCastle. I am still getting OpenSSL result on Android.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no discrepancy between the keys. One is printed in base-16 (hexadecimal) whereas the other is printed in decimal. Just try the following code for reassurance:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(
    "90d3b5cefc50dc42828cee8d718876f7573b4c9287dddf808e73cb66266c2004165217f86d0f0192de0bb88b3aac2002303ee8b1c926e9bc54189a5ec5a12bb293df0b3c6ff2458a63098f712f0b72218ce301c38de3971ae8c6c646160a5e2e24dc07679e5a82ada1233ecf5eca3d0d1f483d1c9f059a23deed537c670b70b1",
    16);
System.out.println(bi.toString(10));
```

The result will be the same as your non OpenSSL key.

What's happening here is that your different platforms have different *cryptographic providers* that perform the crypto operations. The results will be the same, but there will be small idiosyncrasies that will be noticed, for example, when calling `toString()`.

Comment: Never thought of that! I had to use a different implementation(Spongy Castle) on both device and backend. Thanks Duncan